# Clear a selection in Firefox

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I have this function

```
function smth() {
var container = null;
var newContainer = null;
if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    alert("first if");
    var selectionRange = window.getSelection();
    if (selectionRange.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = selectionRange.getRangeAt(0);
        container = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        newContainer = container;
    }
}
else {
    if (document.selection) {   // Internet Explorer
        alert("second if");
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        container = textRange.parentElement();
    }
}

if (newContainer) {
    return newContainer.nodeName;
}
else {
    alert("Container object for the selection is not available!");
}
}
```

Now after i do what i need to do with the selection i need to clear it. i tried a few things nothing worked, any ideas?

```
document.selection.clear ()
```

this didnt work.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

For the problematic browser:

```
document.selection.empty()
```

For other browsers:

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
```

See http://help.dottoro.com/ljigixkc.php

Comment: Won't work as expected for example inside a tinymce editor window (an iframe actually). You will need to use: tinymce.activeEditor.selection.collapse();

Comment: "For the problematic browser" is not the case anymore. The latter option here works for all browsers, including the recent versions of IE. (Assuming you meant IE by "problematic.")

Answer (score 0):

Note: in case you are selecting the text of an input or textarea element then your code would have more cross browser support if you would use the standard native html element select method of the input or textarea.

If an html input or textarea element was selected using the native select method then using the methods suggested above does not work on my firefox 44.0.2. What worked for it, and I suppose works on ALL BROWSERS, is running the following code which creates a new element and selects it. The new element can't be with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` because then it is not selected in my Firebox so the trick is to make it invisible by forcing all size attributes to `0\none`.

```
var tempElement = document.createElement("input");
tempElement.style.cssText = "width:0!important;padding:0!important;border:0!important;margin:0!important;outline:none!important;boxShadow:none!important;";
document.body.appendChild(tempElement);
tempElement.select();
/* Use removeChild instead of remove because remove is less supported */
document.body.removeChild(tempElement);
```

Comment: @LawrenceDol Then you could refocus the input field after running this, if losing focus is a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use
    `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.collapse()`
 if that does not work then use
    `const range = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.createRng();
    tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setRng(range)`