# Is there a function to deselect all text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selection

Is there a function in javascript to just deselect all selected text? I figure it's got to be a simple global function like `document.body.deselectAll();` or something.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clearSelection()
{
 if (window.getSelection) {window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();}
 else if (document.selection) {document.selection.empty();}
}
```

This will clear a selection in regular HTML content in any major browser. It won't clear a selection in a text input or `<textarea>` in Firefox.

Comment: I can confirm that `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` works in all current browsers. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hWMJT/1/

Comment: you have to click a button like                                             <input id='but' type='button' value='click'/ onclick='clearSelection()'>

Comment: @Šime - not really. It's "working" because the selection is lost when the button get focus. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/hWMJT/2/) - code is commented, selection is still cleared.

Comment: @Shadow Here is the proper demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9spL8/3/ The `removeAllRanges()` method works in all current browsers for text inside paragraphs or similar non-form-field elements. For form-fields (like textarea), this method doesn't work in IE9 and FF5.

Comment: @Shadow The second method - `document.selection.empty()` - works in IE9 for all types of selections (even form-fields). Therefore, the above code works in all current browsers except for the Firefox/form-field combination (for which there should exist a hack).

Comment: Edited, use `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` *first* because it's standards-compliant, proprietary code should always be executed *last*. Be it the year 2004 or 4004 standards compliant code will always ultimately be what we use so detect it first without exception!

Comment: This causes the caret in a contenteditable div to disappear.

Answer (score 30):

Here's a version that will clear any selection, including within text inputs and textareas:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SLQpM/23/

```
function clearSelection() {
    var sel;
    if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.empty ) {
        sel.empty();
    } else {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
        var activeEl = document.activeElement;
        if (activeEl) {
            var tagName = activeEl.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if ( tagName == "textarea" ||
                    (tagName == "input" && activeEl.type == "text") ) {
                // Collapse the selection to the end
                activeEl.selectionStart = activeEl.selectionEnd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work if your selection starts somewhere from the first line and includes the larger text field

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: That's probably because it's a quickly-made simple example and if you end the selection outside the main `<div>` then the `mouseup` event doesn't fire. Put the mouseup handler on the document instead and it would be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SLQpM/23/

Comment: This is a great work-around in older browsers that don't support user-select CSS when dragging elements around.  Call clearSelection() in the mouse move callback.

Answer (score 8):

This worked incredibly easier for me ...

```
document.getSelection().collapseToEnd()
```

or

```
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
```

Credits: https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/9410/deselect-everything-that-is-selected

Comment: When using collapseToEnd (), an error appears in the console - Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'collapseToEnd' on 'Selection': there is no selection.

Answer (score 7):

For Internet Explorer, you can use the [empty method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536359(v=vs.85).aspx) of the document.selection object:

> document.selection.empty();

For a cross-browser solution, see this answer:

[Clear a selection in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186844/clear-a-selection-in-firefox/6187098#6187098)

Comment: If your website is public (not intranet where you control the browsers) it's not good idea, it's not cross browser.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - true, this question may be relevant for a cross-browser solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186844/clear-a-selection-in-firefox

Comment: @Luke nice, too bad that another website is going to be (probably) not consistent among different browsers as the OP took what you gave as-is.

Comment: In my opinion browser compatibility is something obvious that should be offered by us - many developers aren't even aware such differences exist, so those who know should tell them. This aside, I never said your question is *wrong*, just *missing*.

Comment: @Luke `document.selection.clear()` works **only** in IE. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9spL8/4/ Also, this method will *remove* the selected text, not just deselect it. To just deselect the text, use `document.selection.empty()` instead.

Comment: My mistake, it is Internet Explorer only, and the method should be empty not clear - I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

For a `textarea` element with at least 10 characters the following will make a small selection and then after a second and a half deselect it:

```
var t = document.getElementById('textarea_element');
t.focus();
t.selectionStart = 4;
t.selectionEnd = 8;

setTimeout(function()
{
 t.selectionStart = 4;
 t.selectionEnd = 4;
},1500);
```