# Removing highlighting of misspelled words when contenteditable="false"

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

```js
var editBtn = document.querySelector("button#edit"),
  editable = editBtn.previousElementSibling,
  saveBtn = editBtn.nextElementSibling;

editBtn.addEventListener('click', startEdit, false);
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', endEdit, false);

function startEdit() {
  editable.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  editable.focus();
}

function endEdit() {
  editable.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  // even tried
  // editable.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
p[contenteditable="true"] {
  font-family: "Arial", "Georgia", "Calibri";
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #424245;
  border: 1px solid #C7C6CD;
}
```

```html
<p>click edit, type some mispelled words, click save and highlighting remains</p>
<button id="edit">edit</button>
<button>save</button>
```

I have a feature application that sets `contenteditable="true"` on a `<p></p>` element
when an edit button is clicked, then set it to `false` when the ENTER key is pressed.

Now after the ENTER key is pressed and `contenteditable="false"` is set on the element, all misspelled words highlighted remain highlighted even though now the element is no longer editable.

Is there a way to remove the highlighting of misspelled words in this case.

I had problem running the code snippet in the editor, so if there's any problem please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562727/is-there-a-function-to-deselect-all-text-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just overwrite the content with itself:

```
var html = editable.innerHTML;
editable.innerHTML = "";
editable.innerHTML = html;
```

Emptying the content first is necessary, unfortunately.
*Simply `editable.innerHTML = editable.innerHTML;` doesn't seem to work.*

```js
var editBtn = document.querySelector("button#edit"),
    editable = editBtn.previousElementSibling,
    saveBtn = editBtn.nextElementSibling;

editBtn.addEventListener('click', startEdit, false);
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', endEdit, false);

function startEdit() {
  editable.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  editable.focus();
}

function endEdit() {
  editable.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  var html = editable.innerHTML;
  editable.innerHTML = "";
  editable.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
p[contenteditable="true"] {
  font-family: "Arial", "Georgia", "Calibri";
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #424245;
  border: 1px solid #C7C6CD;
}
```

```html
<p>click edit, type some mispelled words, click save and highlighting remains</p>
<button id="edit">edit</button>
<button>save</button>
```