# How to prevent highlighting all text when tabbing between inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have many inputs fields which I need to fill repeatedly so I usually use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate through the form.

Fields have default suffix value which needs to be prepended. It works as expected when I focus in the input with mouse click.

However when I tab between inputs it selects all text which is undesirable behaviour in my case.

Have a look at this:

```js
function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
  if (elem == null) return;
  if (elem.createTextRange) {
    var range = elem.createTextRange();
    range.move('character', caretPos);
    range.select();
  } else if (elem.selectionStart) {
    elem.focus();
    elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
  } else {
    elem.focus();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').focus(function() {
    setCaretPosition(this, 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" value=" km/h" />
<input type="text" id="input2" value=" kg" />
```

- When you click inside any of the inputs, caret is set at the beginning.
- When you <kbd>Tab</kbd> between inputs caret is not set. Instead, whole input contents is higlighted.

How do I prevent text input from higlighting its contents when using tab navigation?

I prefer the answer without use of `setTimeout` (if it's possible at all).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a function to deselect all text using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562727/is-there-a-function-to-deselect-all-text-using-javascript)

Comment: If you think it is a duplicate, why don't you vote to close with the duplicate as a reason?

Comment: Are you sure it's working when clicking? The caret is not moved to position 0 when clicked!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It definitely works on latest Firefox. I don't really need compatibility with other browsers as it's intended to work in my internal tool.

Comment: Note: Caret will be set to the end of the value in Chrome. FF and IE set to the beginning. I know you said you don't care about cross compatibility, just a note for others.

Comment: You could remove the appearance of selection with CSS. It would still overwrite the original input if you didn't manually move the cursor. Is this a validation question? You could use the client or server to prefix the value if it wasn't entered by the user.

Comment: If it's an internal tool, surely you can do away with UX and just validate and prefix if needed on the client or server side (once the form is submitted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On Chrome and Explorer(Not working on Edge and Firefox), simply:**

```html
<input type="text" value=" km/h" onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length, this.value.length)"/>
<input type="text" value=" kg" onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length, this.value.length)"/>
```

**On Firefox and Chrome(Not working on Edge and Explorer)**

```js
jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // Cache references
    var $el = $(this), el = this;
    
    // Timeout seems to be required for Firefox
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.setSelectionRange($el.val().length, $el.val().length);
    }, 0);
  });
};

var searchInput = $("input");

searchInput.on("focus", function() { // could be on any event
    searchInput.putCursorAtEnd()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value=" km/h" />
<input type="text" value=" kg" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. When I focus on first input and click Tab, it focuses on second input and selects all its contents. Tested on latest Firefox.

Comment: Can confirm that FF behaves differently :(

Comment: Confirmed too, works on chrome and explorer, not working on firefox and edge will look into it

Comment: It seems setTimeout is required for firefox and IE, even if the time is set to 0