# How to get textarea's cursor move to the end of the highlighted text on drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I drag and drop the image into the textarea, the text is highlighted. 

Is there a way to have the textarea's cursor move to the end of the highlighted text?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.emoteImage').forEach((emoteImage) => {
  emoteImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', emoteImage.alt);
    event.effectAllowed = "copy";
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emote">
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ficons.iconarchive.com%2Ficons%2Fpaomedia%2Fsmall-n-flat%2F512%2Fcat-icon.png&f=1" alt="emote1" title="emote1" class="emoteImage">
</div>


<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562727/is-there-a-function-to-deselect-all-text-using-javascript

Comment: The linked solutions still show the text in the textarea remaining highlighted after the drop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added a "dragEnd" event to move the cursor to the end of the highlighted text.
Hope it helps :)

```js
var element = document.getElementById("textArea");

document.querySelectorAll('.emoteImage').forEach((emoteImage) => {
  emoteImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', emoteImage.alt);
    event.effectAllowed = "copy";


});

emoteImage.addEventListener( 'dragend', function( event ) {
    var end = element.selectionEnd ;
    element.focus();
    element.setSelectionRange(end,end);
});

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emote">
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ficons.iconarchive.com%2Ficons%2Fpaomedia%2Fsmall-n-flat%2F512%2Fcat-icon.png&f=1" alt="emote1" title="emote1" class="emoteImage">
</div>


<textarea id="textArea" ></textarea>
```