# How to deselect text in a `ICoreWebView2` control?

Tags: webview, webview2

Assume that we have 2 `ICoreWebView2` controls in a panel, and they are X and Y. When there is any text selected in X, if we then select text in Y, we can observe that the text we selected in X is still selected, even though X has lost keyboard focus, which is now in Y.

How do we "deselect all" in X, when X loses keyboard focus?

By the way, this (deselecting all in X) is the default behavior on WebKit2, but `ICoreWebView2` has different behavior. To make our application cross-platform, we need them to have the same behavior so that other codes won't be confused by multiple selected texts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Just call [this JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562727/is-there-a-function-to-deselect-all-text-using-javascript#answer-6562764) on X, whenever Y gets the keyboard focus.